# STL map instantiating

Tags: c++, stl

have next code:

```
class GameTexture
{
private:
LPDIRECT3DTEXTURE9 texture;
unsigned char *alphaLayer;
UINT width, height;

GameTexture() {};
GameTexture(const GameTexture&) {}
public:
static GameTexture *CreateTexture(LPCTSTR  pSrcFile, LPDIRECT3DDEVICE9 d3dDevice);

~GameTexture();
};

class TexturesPool
{
private:
map<string, GameTexture*> textures;
```

and got next

```
1>c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\xfunctional(125): error C2784: 'bool std::operator <(const std::_Tree<_Traits> &,const std::_Tree<_Traits> &)' : could not deduce template argument for 'const std::_Tree<_Traits> &' from 'const std::string'
1>          c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\xtree(1885) : see declaration of 'std::operator <'
1>          c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\xfunctional(124) : while compiling class template member function 'bool std::less<_Ty>::operator ()(const _Ty &,const _Ty &) const'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Ty=std::string
1>          ]
1>          c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\map(71) : see reference to class template instantiation 'std::less<_Ty>' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Ty=std::string
1>          ]
............
```

Comment: post summary/probable source of problem > ?

Comment: its because of using GameTexture* in map, if replace with int all goes well, but i need map with pointers to my objects

Comment: Your code, as pasted, is correct. The error probably arises from an incorrect use of the _textures_ variable, look into the compiler output, next to the pasted error.

Comment: Could you please make actual sentences in your question?

Comment: As a slight improvement to your code, might I suggest you use shared/unique_ptr over holding raw pointers in your container.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's possible that you're missing `#include <string>` which is where the missing `operator<` should be declared.

Some of MSVC's headers forward-declare std::string, but do not actually include `<string>` itself.